# Loading state of in-progress game in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios6, nsuserdefaults

One of the iOS games that I really like (Fieldrunners 2) allows user to continue his/her game even after the app is killed mid-level (during game play). When the user launches the app again, it asks whether the user wants to continue the in-progress level.

How are they doing this? WHat is the easiest and smartest way (cocos2d and ios) to reload an in-progress game? It seems to me that there are so many states that need to be saved. Is it as tedious as I think it is?

EDIT:
When I say `killed`, I double clicked the home button and then I pressed and held on the app's icon and click the x icon.

Comment: But the app will not lose any of its states as long as it did not get entirely quit (by the user or the system). In case you are talking about a full quit, then I guess its all about proper state persistence in your engine -> deserializing all states into the filesystem.

Comment: when i mean by `killed` is that I double click the home button and then I hold on the app's icon and click the x mark.

Comment: Ok, got ya - that indeed is a case for proper state persistence - commonly done via user defaults - and yes, in case your engine is not prepared for such thing, it quickly gets rather tedious.

Comment: Nobody seems to be responding to this.... you can use your comment to answer this and I will gladly accept yours as the answer.